# Display the posts in facebook application

Tags: android, facebook

How Display the posts in facebook application. I tried to work with sample android API for Facebook. But nothing worked fine. I need to display a post that i post on my Facebook wall in android emulator. I need a sample code to run and display the JSON response as my post.

Please  send me few working links.

Comment: I think you should put some code here.

Answer (score 2):

**Attach the given code with your facebook login class**

```
public void postOnWall() {

    try {

           String response = Config.facebook.request("me");
           Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
           parameters.putString("access_token", Config.myAccessToken);

           parameters.putString("message", "I am Now On FB");
           parameters.putString("description", "");
           response = Config.facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, 
                   "POST");

           if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                   response.equals("false")) {

           }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be preferable to give an explanation to your answer.  While this *might* be the correct answer - it would be [a lot more useful](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) if you included your reasoning/logic.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code and sdk official for facebook on android

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/examples/stream/src/com/facebook/stream/StreamHandler.java

```
public class StreamHandler extends Handler {

    private static final String CACHE_FILE = "cache.txt";

    /**
     * Called by the dispatcher to render the stream page.
     */
    public void go() {
        dispatcher.getWebView().addJavascriptInterface(
                new StreamJsHandler(this), "app");

        // first try to load the cached data
        try {
            String cached = FileIO.read(getActivity(), CACHE_FILE);
            if (cached != null) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(cached);
                dispatcher.loadData(StreamRenderer.render(obj));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Facebook fb = Session.restore(getActivity()).getFb();
        new AsyncFacebookRunner(fb).request("me/home", 
                new StreamRequestListener());
    }

    public class StreamRequestListener implements RequestListener {

        public void onComplete(String response, final Object state) {
            try {
                JSONObject obj = Util.parseJson(response);
                // try to cache the result
                try {
                    FileIO.write(getActivity(), response, CACHE_FILE);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Convert the result into an HTML string and then load it
                // into the WebView in the UI thread.
                final String html = StreamRenderer.render(obj);
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        dispatcher.loadData(html);
                    }
                });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("stream", "JSON Error:" + e.getMessage());
            } catch (FacebookError e) {
                Log.e("stream", "Facebook Error:" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, final Object state) {
            Log.e("stream", "Facebook Error:" + e.getMessage());
        }

        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                                            final Object state) {
            Log.e("stream", "Resource not found:" + e.getMessage());      
        }

        public void onIOException(IOException e, final Object state) {
            Log.e("stream", "Network Error:" + e.getMessage());      
        }

        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                                            final Object state) {
            Log.e("stream", "Invalid URL:" + e.getMessage());            
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Does Facebook on android application requires API version 8 to run.

Comment: no its not neccassary for facebook sdk to run on min version 8 on android